# Oracle Weblogic OAM get user information using session cookies

Tags: oracle, weblogic, session-cookies, weblogic11g, oracle-fusion-middleware

Oracle/WebLogic noob here. I'm not sure if I'm asking the right questions but any and all tips will be greatly appreciated.

We are trying to deploy an Angular 4 web application on to an Oracle WebLogic server w Apache HTTP and security managed by OAM. The user will be directed to the OAM login screen initially and once they log in they will be directed to the Angular app.

One of my tasks is to get the user's userid to display on the navigation at the top, one of my colleagues suggested grabbing the information from one of the http cookies but I could not figure out where/which cookie it is. I looked all over the place and the only relevant cookie that I've found is the OAMAuthnCookie which contains the encrypted session related ID.

I don't think this is possible without some customization on the server-side, any straight-forward answers or suggestions to accomplish my task will be very helpful. Does WebLogic / OAM provide a web service I can use from my client-side Angular app to access the user information i'm looking for?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5):

i think you may use;

- `oam_req` cookie (set by the OAM server)

or

- `oamRequestContext` cookie( set by 11g WebGate )

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, either of you guys know any other methods to access the user information such as a web service / REST API other than session cookies?

Comment: @ZvKa you're welcome zvka, i suppose, this can be a good resource  : [link](http://javapapers.com/web-service/restful-services-http-basic-authentication/)

Comment: Sorry I meant to be more specific, wanted to know if there are any EXISTING services from OAM/WebGate that I can utilize, not develop a new service from scratch. Thanks!